# jquery extension not working on multiple instances

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I put up this fiddle here :  http://jsfiddle.net/4wBK4/

and what's going on is if you use only ONE `cardFlip` HTML block (it's green), it works as expected. You click on the `switch` element inside and it does it's effect.

But as soon as I have TWO of these on the page - as is the case in the fiddle until you remove one of them -, nothing works anymore.

but Idont get it. I think I'm doing it right, and each instance should have its own event fired - but I guess I'm misunderstanding something about how the CSS animations are applied to elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some fiddling (pun intended), and also seeing this ([jquery plugin multiple instance not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550108/jquery-plugin-multiple-instance-not-working)) question, I realized my error:

The problem is the `.on()` event. I changed it from `$(document).on({...},'.context')` to this: `$(this).parents('.context').on({...})`